# Can I use a PC hard disk drive for my PS3?

Tags: ps3, hard-drive

I have a 12 GB super slim play station 3, when I bought it I thought that 12 GB would be enough for few games but it's actually not once I tried it. I was wondering if I could connect a PC hard disk drive to my Playstation 3 instead of buying a hard disk drive for it?  Is there any way that I can connect an PC hard disk drive to my PS3 - I mean to use the PCs hard drive storage space.

Comment: Do you mean to use your PC's hard drive for PS3 storage space, or do you mean to replace the drive for the PS3? It's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Related: [Internal PS3 HDD Replacement](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/17393/4797)

Answer (score 7):

IF you mean an external drive or somehow hooking your PS3 to your PC no, you can't install games on an external drive like that. You can however use a laptop 2.5" HDD and replace the physical HDD inside the PS3 (you can backup and restore your current saves to keep all your stuff too).

See this question for a bit more info on the HDD type you need [Internal PS3 HDD Replacement](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17393/internal-ps3-hdd-replacement)

Answer (score 1):

The typical PC hard disk drive is not the correct size to be placed inside a PS3 console.

Answer (score 1):

No a normal PC hard disk drive the [Sony support site](https://support.us.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/362) states

> The HDD must be a 2.5” internal Serial ATA HDD. Parallel ATA is not supported.

External Hard Drives though USB are supported.

Answer (score 0):

My boyfriend has a 750gb computer hard drive in his ps3. So I'm assuming that yeah you can have a computer hard drive in the ps3

Answer (score -4):

You can buy a hard disc drive which is designed for the PS3. However, the PC disk drive is not the right size for your PS3.

Comment: There are various sizes and types of PC hard disks. Some of them are indeed compatable with PS3. See other answers for details.